# How to display tab bar in different activity in android

Tags: android

I have a tab bar in my application. In this I have three tabs. It will call three activities. In activities I have the list view. If I click the list view, it will call different activities other than tab activities. Can anybody tell me how to display the tab bar for other activities and give an example?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[First, do the tutorial.](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) Then, if you are still having problems, ask more specific questions.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/yifanz/Android-Custom-Tabs/downloads
hope this will help you. making iphone like tab bar for android...